# showing image with get method in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, post, flask, get

I want to display multiple image by get method using flask and reactjs from a image table.I  uploaded the image using post method.But I am not sure how to display it using get method. This is the image table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_lead_image_path(
id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
image_path VARCHAR(255),
);
```

The images are saved in a directory called `visitImageDirectory` through post method

Now i want to display all the images in reactjs.This is what i wrote in the frontnd:

```
this.state = {
        apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
        imageList:[]
    };


getImagePath = () => {
        axios.get( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/visitImageInfo/getImage', {})
            .then((response) => {
                console.log("response",response.data.data);

                this.setState({
                    imageList:response.data.data
                });
                // this.setState({ imageList: response.data.data  });
            }).catch((error)=>{  console.log("error",error); this.setState({ imageList: []  });   });
    };

 render() {

        return (
          <div> {this.state.imageList.map(image =><img src={image}/>)}                           </div> )}
```

I am getting these data as response in the console:

```
   "data": [
        {
          "id": "4aa8aa9d-ab3d-4ab1-aca4-12716fa5a82a",
          "imagePath": "visitImageDirectory/38c37fcd-0273-4884-8661-d9b57ffc5384.png"
        },
        {
          "id": "c159e18f-4dbc-4210-8957-4e9fc9bab68d",
          "imagePath": "visitImageDirectory/c5e01b4f-8925-4e93-a40b-0dc51cbd2345.png"
        }  
      ],
GET http://localhost:3457/setting/furnitureVenture/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

But i cant display the image.How i can do  it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you need to reference the `imagePath` on the image object.

Like so:

```
return (
   <div> {this.state.imageList.map(image => (<img src={image.imagePath}/>) )}</div>
);
```

And depending on what the relative URL of where the img tag is output, you may need to add a fully qualified URL to the beginning of the imagePath: `src={'/path/to/folder/' + image.imagePath}`

Edit:
Try to visit http://localhost:3457/setting/furnitureVenture/visitImageDirectory/c5e01b4f-8925-4e93-a40b-0dc51cbd2345.png and if you see an image you can ignore the qualified URL part, but if the `visitImageDirectory` is not inside the `/setting/furnitureVenture` folder, then you'll need to update the '/path/to/folder/' to be the folder path that contains `visitImageDirectory`

Comment: the ```visit image directory``` doesnot exist in the frontend.Its a different folder in the backend.If i want to specifically show a single a image in the url it would be like this.
```http://localhost:5000/api/v1/visitImageInfo/getImage?visitImagePath=visitImageDirectory/38c37fcd-0273-4884-8661-d9b57ffc5384.png```
But i have not been able to pass the path as you mentioned:

Comment: I tried it like this.Its still not working:
<img src={this.state.apiUrl +'/api/v1/visitImageInfo/getImage/'+ image.imagePath}/>

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the data you are retrieving **doesn't contain the full URL** to the image, also if you save both id and imagePath to imageList you must access the **imagePath property** when mapping. I'm not really sure about your endpoint, but this may help:

```
<img src={this.state.apiUrl + image.imagePath}/>
```